# Ignore inherited class when serializing object

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, inheritance

When I inherit from a class and serialize the new class I get all all properties. 
How can I prevent that? 
I have no control over the class that I inherit from. So I can't add attributes to it's properties (XmlIgnore).

**Example**

```
class A 
{
    public string PropertyA {get;set;}
}

class B:A
{
    public string PropertyB {get;set;}
}
```

When I serialize a object with the type of B then I get both PropertyA and PropertyB and I only want PropertyB

**Xml serialization I use**

```
Type t = serObj.GetType();
XmlSerializer xser = new XmlSerializer(t);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);

xser.Serialize(sw, serObj);
string xml = sw.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `B` inherits from `A`, it inherits `PropertyA`, and there's nothing you can do about it. If you don't want to serialize `PropertyA` when serializing an instance of `B`, perhaps you shouldn't be inheriting `A` in the first place...

Anyway, I don't think XML serialization can help you with what you're trying to do, unless you implement `IXmlSerializable` yourself...

Comment: Ended up implementing ISerializeable. In WriteXml I itterate through the properties and check what DeclaringType it has and only outputs the ones that don't have the type "A". Thanks. Added WriteXml in a answer.

Answer (score 1):

This was the solution I came up with.

```
        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in this.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                string name = propertyInfo.Name;

                if (propertyInfo.DeclaringType != typeof(A))
                {
                    object obj = propertyInfo.GetValue(this, null);

                    if (obj != null)
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartElement(name);
                        string value = obj.ToString();
                        writer.WriteValue(value);
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use the `[Nonserialized]` attribute on PropertyA.  Note that with this attribute, PropertyA will never be serialized, including when you serialize an instance of class A.  Is that acceptable?

Comment: I should probably had said that I have no control over class A. Will add that to question :)

Comment: NonSerialized has nothing to do with XML serialization... it is used by formatters like BinaryFormatter (binary serialization)

Comment: If I remember, `[XmlIgnore]` is the attribute that accomplishes this, although that doesn't help the OP since the base class is not under control.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but: I just stumbled over your question because I have similar problem. I inherit from a class, but the logic of my derived class renders some properties of the base class redundant or obsolete for serialization, and so I don't want to serialize them.

I found a solution which isn't as automatic as yours but more flexible: Override the base class properties and mark them with `[XmlIgnore]`. The implementation in the override can just consist of a call to the base implementation; the only purpose of the overriding is to attach the XmlIgnore attribute to it.

It's less automatic because if properties in the base class change you have to reflect the changes in the derived class. That's on the other hand more flexible because you can select *which* properties to ignore.

Admittedly this solution doesn't scale well and is best suited for smaller projects with close ties between the involved classes and people.